# Elasticsearch 7.17.0 not running in cent os 7

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, systemd

I installed elasticsearch 7.17.0 in cent os 7 . But i could not bring the elastic search instance up and running . Below is the exception seen in the error log .

`[2023-11-24T09:05:44,263][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: sd_notify returned error [-13] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: sd_notify returned error [-13] at org.elasticsearch.systemd.SystemdPlugin.onNodeStarted(SystemdPlugin.java:127) ~[?:?] at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?] at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:1280) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:335) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:443) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.0.jar:7.17.0]`

ES yml file is untouched all set to defaults. inspecting code i could infer libsystemd.so.0 is being a made a native call

`static native int sd_notify(int unset_environment, String state);`

this method returns -13 causing runtime exception . This has something to do with systemd services but couldnt figure out whats wrong ..

EXpecting application to be up and running healthy

Answer (score 0):

sd_notify() uses the kernel style of returning negative errno.h values; `errno 13` says that it means EACCES ("Permission denied")

Practically the only thing sd_notify() does is connect to a systemd-provided Unix socket, which is normally set to open access. Check its permissions using `namei -l /run/systemd/notify`; the socket should have permissions 0777 (rwx/rwx/rwx) and each of its parent directories should be 0755 (rwx/rx/rx).

Also check `dmesg` for SELinux or AppArmor denials, just in case (although it's not the usual error code for that).

Running the service under `strace`, although somewhat complicated for a Java-based service, would be one way of tracking down such errors.